# Kinect depth with player index + video stream

Tags: c#, kinect

I'm trying to produce an image from the kinect where all pixel that do not represent a player will be set to black.

My idea is to use the data produced by the depthstream with player index along with the videostream to accomplish this task.

My hope was to do something like this:

```
byte[] pixelData = video.imageFrame.Bits;
byte[] depthData = depth.imageFrame.Bits;

var depthIndex = 0;
for (var y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
     var heightOffset = y * width;

     for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
     {
          var index = (x + heightOffset) * 4;

          var distance = GetDistanceWithPlayerIndex(depthData[depthIndex], depthData[depthIndex + 1]);

          if (GetPlayerIndex(depthData[depthIndex]) == 0)
          {
               pixelData[index + BlueIndex] = 0;
               pixelData[index + GreenIndex] = 0;
               pixelData[index + RedIndex] = 0;
          }
     }
}
```

The issue that I am currently working on it trying to get the videostream data to have the same resolution as the depthwithplayerindex.

I've tried to piece some stuff together from other posts on here but I can't get it to work:

```
private byte[] ScaleVideoImage(ImageFrame imageFrame, int newWidth, int newHeight)
        {
            //convert imageFrame to byte array
            Byte[] oPixelData = imageFrame.Image.Bits;

            Image tempImage = BytesToImg(oPixelData);
            //scale image
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

                graphics.DrawImage(tempImage, 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
            }
            //Convert image to byte array
            MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream();
            bmp.Save(ms1, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            byte[] result = ms1.GetBuffer();
            bmp.Dispose();
            ms1.Close();
            return result;
        }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the code I've previously shared here: http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/Display-Kinect-color-image-containing-only-players-aka-background-removal